# magento paypal payment not being authorized

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have a Magento based site I am setting up and am using Paypal. The issue is when someone makes a purchase on the site I see the order as authorized only in Paypal and I have to login to paypal to click a button to "capture" the money and actually charge the card. I have the Paypal settings in magento admin panel set to "sale" the only other option listed is "authorized" which is not what I want. I want when someone is on the site and orders for their card to be charged and for the money to be taken from their card.

Can anyone suggest what my issue may be. The site is using Magento Enterprise edition if that helps.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your Paypal settings for following:

1. Is Auto return set to on.
2. Is IPN set to on.

If these two are ok and still you face this issue then you will need to log what all is posted by paypal to your site wen payment is received.

If you have not modified Paypal module(should be the case) and no firewall issues of your server then most probably its your paypal configuration.